# How to reset hosts file back to default?

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

How do I reset my hosts file back to default?

**Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit**

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default `hosts` file configuration for Windows 7 from [Microsoft Support: How can I reset the Hosts file back to the default?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034)

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handle within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
```

Comment: nice one Jin, one more question, what if I've deleted my hosts file completely? Any idea how to create a new one? Say go to Notepad, add this piece of info you gave, now what extension should i save it?

Comment: @V413HAV No extensions, filename is simply `hosts`. See step 3 in the [link I've attached](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways).

Comment: Cool Buddy :) :)

Comment: All lines starting with `#` are simply ignored, so you might as well leave the file empty.

Comment: and set it to read only just for fun.

Comment: @Psycogeek: AFAIK, it *is* read-only -- protected by NTFS ACLs.

Comment: @Psycogeek grawity is right, so i often edit a copy of hosts and replace it with original.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has created an [automatic fix for this certain problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034). If you want to try and fix it manually here are the steps how:

- Type this in the Run window (click Start > Run):

  ```
  %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc
  ```

  (where system root is your default main root folder, usually `C:`).
- Change the name of the `hosts` file to `hosts.old`
- Open Windows Explorer and go to the `%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Etc` folder  (`WinDir` is your Windows directory)
- Create a new text document, name it `hosts`, make sure the file extension is not text (`.txt`)
- Open the new `hosts` file using Notepad or any other text editor.
- Since you're using XP, here is what the contents of the hosts file should be:

  [image]