# google.com redirects to googledesktop.blogspot.com

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

I have been using college wifi for quite a while. About a week ago, whenever I used to search using google.com it shows up as Google Desktop has been discontinued and then redirects to googledesktop.blogspot.com

[The redirected website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcPkW.png)

[When I enter google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7tAz.png)

Comment: Which operating system you're using?

Comment: windows 10 operating system

Comment: First time I hear about such a behavior. Run an antivirus and anti-malware check just to be sure.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Ran a deep scan and antimalware check. Also tried running windows in safe mode. Still, the problem persists. Installed HTTPS everywhere and problem solved.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling [Google Desktop](https://support.google.com/answer/2801289).

Here are steps for Windows:

> 1. Click the Start menu button in your Windows taskbar.
> 2. Go to *Programs > Google Desktop > Uninstall Google Desktop*.
> 3. Select the 'Remove completely for all users' option.
> 4. Click the *Yes* button.
> 5. If you'd like to delete your personal search index as well, deselect the 'Keep index and gadgets' tick box.
> 6. Click the Uninstall button to complete the process.

If you don't have administrator right, ask your administrator to do it.

For Mac or Linux, follow the above link.

---

If above won't help, here are more suggestions:

- Check the custom entries in your `hosts` file and remove them. See: [How to reset hosts file back to default?](https://superuser.com/q/343925/87805)
- Check what kind of DNS servers you're using, and consider changing them to [OpenDNS](https://use.opendns.com/) or [Google Public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) one (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`).
- Uninstall suspicious extension from your web browser, use private/incognito mode, or use different one.
- Use https://www.google.com/ (with HTTPS), not `http://www.google.com/`

Comment: The last point using HTTPS worked! Is this an issue caused by the browser or the usage of college wifi?

Comment: If the PC doesn't have _Google Desktop_, maybe admin set up some firewall rules for HTTP.